# Changing name of variable makes code not work

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have the following code to run an angular app from a node.js server:

```
const root = path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/dist', 'learn-playV2');

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  fs.stat(root + req.path, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.sendFile("index.html", {root});
    } else {
      res.sendFile(req.path, {root});
    }
  })
});
app.listen(port);
```

But I want to be able to change the 'root' variable to 'rootLocal' (I want to have an option for the root) based on how I run the app

```
const rootLocal = path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/dist', 'learn-playV2');

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  fs.stat(rootLocal + req.path, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.sendFile("index.html", {rootLocal});
    } else {
      res.sendFile(req.path, {rootLocal});
    }
  })
});
app.listen(port);
```

For some reason, my code won't run when I do this, even though neither variable is anywhere else in my code. I get this error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\index.html'

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `sendFile` expects an object with `root`:

Try this:

```
if (err) {
  res.sendFile("index.html", { root: rootLocal });
} else {
  res.sendFile(req.path, { root: rootLocal });
}
```

The object creation `{ root }` is shorthand for `{ root: root }`